# Trimming a string

Tags: c++, strings

> **Function: Trim**
>
> Returns a new string after removing any white-space characters from
>   the beginning and end of the argument.

```
string trim(string word) {

    if(startsWith(word, " ")) return removeSpaces(word, "Front");
    if(endsWith(word, " ")) return removeSpaces(word , "Back");
    return word;
}

string removeSpaces(string word , string position){

    if(position == "Front"){
        for(int i =0;  i <word.length();i++){
            if(word[i] != ' '){
                return word;
            }else{
                word.erase(i);
            }
        }
        return word;

    }else if(position == "Back"){
        for(int i =word.length() - 1 ;  i >=0 ; i--){
            if(word[i] != ' '){
                return word;
            }else{
                word.erase(i);
            }
        }
        return word;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why there isn't a `trim()` method available as part of the string library? [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28string_functions%29#trim) has it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument to `removeSpaces` should by no means be a `string`. I suggest an `enum`:

```
enum StringPostion {
    BEGINNING_OF_STRING,
    END_OF_STRING,
};
```

---

You appear to have a `using namespace std;` statement in your program. You shouldn't do this. [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) explains why.

---

Your implementation of `trim` removes spaces from the front or back of `word`, not both.

---

You've chosen an O(kn) algorithm (which is in any case incorrect), where k is the number of spaces at the beginning of the string and n is the number of characters in the string. Each call to `s.erase(i)` causes all of the characters after `i` to be shifted to the left. It also causes the string to be shortened by one character. Your function will only erase half of the leading or trailing spaces since you shorten the string *and* increment `i`.

Try this:

```
std::string trim(std::string word) {
  removeSpaces(word, BEGINNING_OF_STRING);
  removeSpaces(word, END_OF_STRING);
  return word;
}
void removeSpaces(std::string& word, StringPosition position) {
  switch (position) {
    case BEGINNING_OF_STRING: {
      const auto first_nonspace = word.find_first_not_of(' ');
      word.erase(0, first_nonspace);
      return;
    }
    case END_OF_STRING: {
      const auto last_nonspace = word.find_last_not_of(' ');
      if (last_nonspace != std:string::npos) word.erase(last_nonspace + 1);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Dude!!!! Eye Opening explanation :) still more insights are needed.. when i was writing this code i thought that it will work fine., but how can we get to know about the hidden fail cases of our code.? and i have not seen this "O(kn) algorithm" where can i get to know similar kind of algo .. ?

Comment: Unit testing is very important. I think that Google's C++ unit testing library is pretty good: https://code.google.com/p/googletest/ . A simple unit test where you passed "   foo   " and didn't get "foo" in return would have pointed out your errors.

Comment: "O(kn) algorithm" is shorthand for something like "As the size of your input increases, the number of instructions executed by your algorithm will increase linearly in k and n." This is big-O notation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation, which is widely used by computer scientists to describe the performance of an algorithm. The main point here is that your algorithm performs poorly compared with mine because you remove one character, copy all the other characters one slot to the left, and then repeat. Mine copies all the non-space characters once, instead of once for each space.

Comment: @AravinthChandran In your edit comment, you asked what precisely `const auto first_nonspace = word.find_first_not_of(' ');` means. `auto` gives `first_nonspace` the same type as the expression on the right side of the assignment operator (in this case, `std::string::size_type`, which is the same as `std::size_t` in most implementations but not required to be). `const auto` means that you add a `const` qualifier to the type, making `first_nonspace` a `const std::string::size_type`. `auto` is a new feature in the 2011 C++ standard.

Comment: @AravinthChandran: To add onto that: using `std::string::size_type`, `auto`, or `std::size_t` also guarantees that you can store the string size, no matter how large it is.  Related discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181079/stringsize-type-instead-of-int).

Comment: @Murph I've clarified my comment. My point was that the implementation of `trim` in the question only trims from one side, despite the comment that it should trim from both.

Comment: @ruds I *completely* missed that! Yes, the code is broken.

Answer (score 4):

Since there is no common code between the two code paths within removeSpaces you should have two separate functions:

```
string removeSpacesFromFront(string word) 
string removeSpacesFromBack(string word)
```

Comment: Same idea I had earlier (also the main cause for the confusion in my answer), but I never thought about separate functions.  Good find.

Answer (score 4):

We can simplify this:

```
std::string trim(std::string const& input)
{
    std::string::size_type start = input.find_first_not_of(" ");
    std::string::size_type end   = input.find_last_not_of(" ");

    start = (start == std::string::npos ? 0 : start);
    end   = (end   == std::string::npos ? 0 : end  );

    return input.substr(start, end-start);
}
```

Notice a couple of things:

We don't copy the string. Pass it in by const reference.

We work out where in the input string the start and end are. Then we use the string `substr()` method to just hack out the part we need once.

There are a whole bunch of string manipulation functions in string that make this easy.

OK. So I cheated and it does not do white space just space. So think of this is draft one. A tiny bit of extra effort and we can do the same thing but check for white space by using `std::isspace()`.

I would also think about a version that modifies the input string:

```
void trim_in_place(std::string& input)   // Pass by reference.
{
    std::string::size_type start = input.find_first_not_of(" ");
    std::string::size_type end   = input.find_last_not_of(" ");

    start = (start == std::string::npos ? 0 : start);
    end   = (end   == std::string::npos ? 0 : end  );

    // Create the result
    std::string result = input.substr(start, end-start);

    // Swap it into the input variable (once we know everything has worked).
    swap(result, input)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- Your absence of `std::` before your `string`s lead me to believe that you're using `using namespace std;`.  [Don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
- If-statements don't look too clear as just one line.  Try this instead:

  ```
  if (startsWith(word, " "))
  {
      return removeSpaces(word, "Front");
  }
  ```
- With `std::string`, it's best to use its iterators instead of indices in a for-loop:

  ```
  for (auto iter = str.begin(); iter != str.end(); ++iter)
  {
      // do something with string
  }
  ```

  However, this won't work well in this particular function since you're reducing the size.  For that, I would prefer a while-loop.
- In case you ever want to remove *all* whitespace from an `std::string`:

  ```
  str.erase(remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), isspace), str.end());
  ```

  It's quite clear and safe since it uses the STL.  Include `<algorithm>` to use `remove_if()`.

Comment: Your erase-remove will work to remove all the spaces from a string, but doesn't fulfill the stated contract of the function (remove whitespace from the beginning and end of the string). So for example, it will do the wrong thing for "  hi   there   ".

Comment: @ruds: I see.  I somehow thought it said _starting from_ (and the function name isn't specific enough).  I'll keep it here for generality.

Comment: I disagree with one-line `if`s. They are common, concise and often more readable than their multiline counterparts. (Also, Bjarne uses them.)

Comment: @Lstor: He does?  That's good enough for me, then.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is now 2023, I thought I'd add on a nice clean way to do this using `std::ranges` in C++23.  Most of the other points I'd have made were covered years ago in the other reviews.

```
std::string trim(std::string word) {
    return word 
        | std::views::drop_while(isspace)
        | std::views::reverse
        | std::views::drop_while(isspace)
        | std::views::reverse
        | std::ranges::to<std::string>()
        ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if I were doing this, I'd treat the `string` like a normal collection, and use standard algorithms to do the searching. Instead of comparing directly with `' '`, I'd also rather see `std::isspace` (or something similar) used to determine whether something is a space or not.

Since the standard algorithms all use iterators, we can pretty easily make one piece of code work for trimming either the beginning or end of a string by passing normal or reverse iterators.

With that idea in place, things fall together pretty simply:

```
template <class Iter>
Iter ltrim(Iter b, Iter e) {
    return std::find_if_not(b, e, isspace);
}

std::string ltrim(std::string const &in) {
    return std::string(ltrim(in.begin(), in.end()), in.end());
}

std::string rtrim(std::string const &in) {
    return std::string(in.begin(), ltrim(in.rbegin(), in.rend()).base());
}

std::string trim(std::string const &in) {
    return ltrim(rtrim(in));
}
```

For the full trim, you might prefer to avoid the intermediate result, and instead search for the positions, and create one new string from both positions:

```
std::string trim(std::string const &in) {
    auto b = std::find_if_not(in.begin(), in.end(), isspace);
    auto e = std::find_if_not(in.rbegin(), in.rend(), isspace).base();
    return std::string(b, e);
}
```